# iOS Core Data iCloud sync - make optional

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I'd like to add iCloud syncing to my CoreData based app, and make it an option rather than the only state. From what I see, in iOS 7+ adding iCloud boils down to adding

```
@{NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: @"MyCloudStore"}
```

Options dictionary to `addPersistentStoreWithType:...` call, and responding to `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` by merging the incoming data.

Does this mean that to enable/disable iCloud syncing in the app, I just need to re-add the store to the `persistentStoreCoordinator` with the appropriate options and add/remove the  `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` observer? Would there be any issues using the same local SQLite file?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not sufficient, you need also to react on the NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification and NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification .

Also you need to reflect your functionality, e.g. if you have initial data you need to think about what happened when the app will be installed on the 2nd device/peer to avoid duplicate data.

Additionally you need to check whether or/not the account changes, and some more issues.

There is a very good documentation from apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013491-CH1-SW1 which gives  a good description what needs to be considered.